# Wikipedia pages co-edit graph extraction using Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, wikipedia

I am trying the build the graph of Wikipedia co-edited pages using hadoop. The raw data contains the list of edits, i.e. has one row per edit telling who edited what:

```
# revisionId pageId userId
1 1 10
2 1 11
3 2 10
4 3 10
5 4 11
```

I want to extract a graph, in which each node is a page, and there is a link between two pages if at lease one editor edited both pages (the same editor). For the above example, the output would be:

```
# edges: pageId1,pageId2
1,2
1,3
1,4
2,3
```

I am far from being an expert in Map/Reduce, but I think this has to be done in two jobs:

1. The first job extracts the list of edited pages for each user.

   ```
   # userId pageId1,pageId2,...
   10 1,2,3
   11 1,4
   ```
2. The second job takes the output above, and simply generates all pairs of pages that each user edited (these pages have thus been edited by the same user, and will therefore be linked in the graph). As a bonus, we can actually count how many users co-edited each page, to get the weight of each edge.

   ```
   # pageId1,pageID2 weight
   1,2 1
   1,3 1
   1,4 1
   2,3 1
   ```

I implemented this using Hadoop, and it works. The problem is that the map phase of the second job is really slow (actually, the first 30% are OK, but then it slows down quite a lot). The reason I came up with is that because some users have edited many pages, the mapper has to generate a lot of these pairs as outputs. Hadoop thus has to spill to disk, rendering the whole thing pretty slow.

My questions are thus the following:

1. For those of you who have more experience than I with Hadoop: am I doing it wrong? Is there a simpler way to extract this graph?
2. Can disk spills be the reason why the map phase of the second job is pretty slow? How can I avoid this?

As a side node, this runs fine with a small sample of the edits. It only gets slow with GBs of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a common problem known as combinations/cross-correlation/co-occurrences, and there are two patterns to solve it using Map/Reduce, Pairs or Stripes:

- [Map Reduce Design Patterns :- Pairs & Stripes](http://chandramanitiwary.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/map-reduce-design-patterns-pairs-stripes/)
- [MapReduce Patterns, Algorithms, and Use Cases](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/mapreduce-patterns/) (Cross-correlation section)
- [Pairs and Stripes](http://mycloudresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/13/pairs-and-stripes/)

The way I presented in my question is the pairs approach, which usually generates much more data. The stripes approach benefits more from a combiner, and gave better results in my case.